# Annoying rig parenting issue

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm trying to make an animation like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRm-BSukPds) (not really relevant).

So I downloaded an FPS rig. I reconfigured it for cycles render, and "rigged" the gun to a state I could animate it in (it was one object).

However I cannot get the hand rig to work at all....! I'm guessing they've got some truly fancy settings going on.

I'm using the "child of" constraint to make the gun stick to the hand. But I get some really strange rotation results:

So here, you can see everything is as normal:
[image: Everything is normal]

But then as soon as I move the arm, the gun flips off at a strange angle. Notice how his hand has come right off:
[image: WTF is going on]

[Here's the blend file](https://www.mediafire.com/?76d54ttvu3mciu2). All help is very much appreciated, but remember I'm a complete noob to rigging!

Comment: Why is this on negative 2?!

Answer (score 1):

The Child Of constraint on the gun is targeting the mesh and a vertex group of that mesh.

You want the target to be: Left Armature.001 (pls from now on name your stuff)

And the Bone sub-target: thumb.01.L

Then Set Inverse and position the gun where you need it.

It will stay 'glued' to the bone.

Comment: I didn't make the hands rig! Also, I followed this and it still goes completely insane when I move his wrist.